# How to certify an application for Windows 8?

Tags: .net, windows-8

I currently manage a large suite of applications developed in `C# &.NET 3.51`. Now that Windows 8 is out, some customers and internal stakeholders want these applications to run in Windows 8 (client-side applications at least). My IT group is yet to certify Win8 for internal use. 
From technical standpoint how do I go about doing it? From code perspective, what would I need to do?

Answer (score 0):

These applications would be considered "desktop apps" in Windows 8 (as opposed to Windows Store apps).  There are resources to test compatibility with Windows 8 (including a [Compatibility Cookbook](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=245076)) and info on Windows 8 certification of desktop apps at http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/dd535817.